# Ignite: ERROR: log4j enabled and classpath settings error?

Tags: log4j, classpath, ignite

After installing ignite, the basic execution of ignite.sh went well.
But, as below apache-ignite-2.11.0-bin/config/default-config.xml
Setting Log4J logging in a file throws an error.

default-config.xml
  <property name="gridLogger">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.logger.log4j.Log4JLogger">
          <!-- log4j configuration file -->
          <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="log4j-config.xml"/>
      </bean>
  </property>

## bashrc file

export IGNITE_HOME=/home/a/apache-ignite-2.11.0-bin
   export IGNITE_LIBS=/home/a/apache-ignite-2.11.0-bin/libs/*
   export IGNITE_HOME=/home/a/apache-ignite-2.11.0-bin
   #export IGNITE_LIBS=${IGNITE_HOME}/libs/*
   #export USER_LIBS=/home/a/apache-ignite-2.11.0-bin/libs/*
   export PATH=$PATH:$IGNITE_HOME/bin
   ##export USER_LIBS=$IGNITE_HOME/libs/optional/ignite-log4j/ignite-log4j-2.11.0.jar
   #export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$IGNITE_HOME/libs/ignite-core-2.11.0.jar

## ignite execute

[error]
    root@a-VirtualBox:/home/a/apache-ignite-2.11.0-bin/bin# ./ignite.sh
    WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2     (file:/home/a/apache-ignite-2.11.0-bin/libs/ignite-core-2.11.0.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
    WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of     org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2
    WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
    WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
    class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context (make     sure all classes used in Spring configuration are present at CLASSPATH) [springUrl=file:/home/a/apache-    ignite-2.11.0-bin/config/default-config.xml]
      at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:1098)
      at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:356)
      at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:367)
    Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to instantiate Spring XML     application context (make sure all classes used in Spring configuration are present at CLASSPATH)     [springUrl=file:/home/a/apache-ignite-2.11.0-bin/config/default-config.xml]
      at     org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.applicationContext(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.ja    va:387)
      at     org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.ja    va:104)
      at     org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.ja    va:98)
      at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.loadConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:741)
      at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:942)
      at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:851)
      at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:721)
      at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:690)
      at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:353)
      ... 1 more
    Failed to start grid: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context (make sure all classes     used in Spring configuration are present at CLASSPATH) [springUrl=file:/home/a/apache-ignite-2.11.0-    bin/config/default-config.xml]
    Note! You may use 'USER_LIBS' environment variable to specify your classpath.

Is there a cause of the issue and a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.15.0/logging#using-log4j2), you must first enable the Log4j module. You do that by moving the ignite-log4j2 folder from `libs/optional` to `libs`.